# sklearn image.PatchExtractor in a pipeline throws ValueError

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn

I want to train my image classifier on extracted patches, so I developed the following pipeline, but I keep getting a ValueError and I'm not sure how can I solve it:

```
mlp_pipeline = pipeline.make_pipeline(
image.PatchExtractor(),
DictVectorizer(),
preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(**hyperparameters),
neural_network.MLPClassifier(**hyperparameters))
```

When I attempt to fit the model:

```
_ = mlp_pipeline.fit(train_features, train_target)
```

I get the following error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 _ = mlp_pipeline.fit(train_features, train_target)
      3 _predi = mlp_pipeline.predict(train_features)
      5 _report = metrics.classification_report(
      6     train_target,
      7     _predi,
      8 )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/DSA/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py:378, in Pipeline.fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    352 """Fit the model.
    353 
    354 Fit all the transformers one after the other and transform the
   (...)
    375     Pipeline with fitted steps.
    376 """
    377 fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 378 Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    379 with _print_elapsed_time("Pipeline", self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):
    380     if self._final_estimator != "passthrough":

File ~/anaconda3/envs/DSA/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py:336, in Pipeline._fit(self, X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    334     cloned_transformer = clone(transformer)
    335 # Fit or load from cache the current transformer
--> 336 X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
337     cloned_transformer,
    338     X,
    339     y,
    340     None,
    341     message_clsname="Pipeline",
    342     message=self._log_message(step_idx),
    343     **fit_params_steps[name],
    344 )
    345 # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    346 # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer
    347 # from the cache.
    348 self.steps[step_idx] = (name, fitted_transformer)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/DSA/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/memory.py:349, in NotMemorizedFunc.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    348 def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 349     return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/DSA/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py:872, in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    870         res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    871     else:
--> 872         res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
    874 if weight is None:
    875     return res, transformer

File ~/anaconda3/envs/DSA/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/image.py:551, in PatchExtractor.transform(self, X)
    532 """Transform the image samples in `X` into a matrix of patch data.
    533 
    534 Parameters
   (...)
548      number of patches that can be extracted.
    549 """
    550 self.random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)
--> 551 n_images, i_h, i_w = X.shape[:3]
    552 X = np.reshape(X, (n_images, i_h, i_w, -1))
    553 n_channels = X.shape[-1]
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: What's the shape of `train_features`?

Comment: 10k~ rows and 1024 features. The features represent 32x32 pixel images

Comment: The last line in the traceback suggests you should be passing it as a 3d array, shape 10k, 32, 32.

Comment: And the docs pages agrees: transform expects input of shape "(n_samples, image_height, image_width) or (n_samples, image_height, image_width, n_channels)"

Comment: I will rework my process to account for this. Thanks.